# Why can't you import python 2 modules in python 3?

Tags: python, module, encapsulation

Is there any theoretical reason that stops this? As far as I know python modules can be written in C? What's the reason you can't call functions written in python 2 in python 3?

Comment: How does Python 3 even know that it's a Python 2 module?

Comment: @Gabe: For a pure-Python module, it doesn't… until it gets a `SyntaxError`. (And if it doesn't get one, it works, just as BrenBarn's answer says.) For a C extension module, that's a different story, and a complicated one (and for a .pyc/.pyo file distributed without source, a _different_ different story), but I don't think the OP is asking for those details.

Comment: I am asking for those details, why can't you just invoke the python2 system to compile the python 2 module to pyc and call the pyc from python 3?

Comment: Please define what you mean by "Python 2 module".

Answer (score 2):

In some cases you could, if the code was in pure Python *and* written to tbe compatible with both Python 2 and Python 3.

In many cases you can't, because they're different languages, so code written for one isn't necessarily valid code in the other.

Python is interpreted, not compiled, so the actual source code has to be run whenever you use the module.  There is nothing that corresponds to the compiled form of Java.  If the *source code* of your Python module doesn't work with the new Python, then your module will not work.

(There is a bytecode compiled form of Python, but unlike the Java VM it is not a stable, specified target, so the bytecode interpreter might change from one version of Python to another just like the language might.  See [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148959/why-arent-there-other-programming-languages-that-compile-to-python-bytecode) on Programmers StackExchange.)

I don't understand how the issue of C modules is related here.  Python modules written in C have to be recompiled even for different versions of Python 2.

Comment: I don't see how different language is the problem? You can in Java use a module in the latest version which was written 10 years ago. The module obviously has to be compiled with the old compiler but after that it can be called from the new interface. As long as you have a python 2.x system around on your system that has a python 3.x one. I don't see how the module cannot be compiled to python bytecode with the 2.x system and then have that bytecode called with the 3.x system? It's in general possible to call code written in different languages with different completely runtimes.

Comment: @Zorf: Python is not a compiled language, so it is going from the source code every time.  Python bytecode is not a stable, specified VM like the Java VM; it can change between Python versions.

Comment: Ah, I thought python compiled to pyc which was a fairly stable vm. Even if it's interpreted line by line though, it would still be possible to run a py2 compatibility interpreter over the py2 module which returns the representation of all functions and data in its python 3 form which the python 3 runtime can use to call them? Like, it's possible to call interpreted python from C in an FFI so why not interpreted python 2 from interpreted python 3?

Comment: @Zorf: In theory, yes, maybe.  I don't know if there are thorny edge cases.  But in practice, people just focus on porting the source code, which isn't difficult in most cases (and can also be semiautomated).

Comment: Python 2 and Python 3 were never intended to be compatible internally. In fact, the reason Python 3 exists was to be able to make incompatible changes that would not normally be made in a minor version update, e.g. 2.6 to 2.7.  This includes byte codes which may not be compatible even across minor versions.  Besides the usual external data formats, like json and xml serializations, one quasi-internal format that does provide some cross-version compatibility is Python's pickle module.  But code objects do not and never have been, AFAIK.